# XML parsing complexity sub levels

Tags: javascript, html, xml

so I have this XML and I want to parse out the field `<name>` inside `<condition>`.

`<dataPoint>` repeats in this case.

```
</collection> 
      <dataPoint>
            <dataPointId></dataPointId>
            <description>Hi</description>
            <pointType>
                <pointTypeId></pointTypeId>
            </pointType>
             <currentValue>
                <id>870004</id>
                <condition>
                    <id>6</id>
                     <name>Failure</name>
                    <priority>1</priority>
                    <customStyle></customStyle>
                    <reportColor>#202020</reportColor>
                </condition>
            </currentValue>
            <condition>
                <id>6</id>
                <name>What I need</name>
            </condition>
        </dataPoint>
    </collection>
```

I used:

```
    xmlDatapoints=xmlhttp.responseXML;
    var eachDp = dataPointXml.getElementsByTagName("dataPoint");
    for (data=0; data<eachDp.length; data++){
    eachDp[data].getElementsByTagName("condition") [0].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

But this gives me "`Failure`", I want "`What I need`" inside the `<condition>`, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting the first "condition" element.

```
    <condition>
        <id>6</id>
         <name>Failure</name>
        <priority>1</priority>
        <customStyle></customStyle>
        <reportColor>#202020</reportColor>
    </condition>
```